# custom UIView in UITableViewCell blocks uitableviewcell from reciving an event

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, touch-event, touchesbegan

I have a custom UITableViewCell i.e. I subclassed UITableViewCell class
 when populating each cell (or row) of the uitableview, i am creating my custom UITableViewCell, which composes of an image and some labels.

now when I override the following method in my custom 'UITableViewCell' class,

```
 - (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    NSLog(@"CLICKED CLICKED CELL CLICKED CLICKED");
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
 }
```

it never gets called if i click on the custom views i added to the my custom uitableviecell, but it is fine (event triggered) when i click on the region where there is no custom view on top of it.

my goal is simple, i want to detect any touches in each row (uitableviewcell) in the uitableview.

Comment: Have you set the user interaction property of the subviews in your uitableviewcell?

Answer (score 3):

I have experienced a similar problem today, I was unable to select the cell, since it had a custom UIView with a scrollView on it. Try setting `userInteractionIsEnabled = false` on your subviews of your UIView.

Answer (score 0):

plz try to override this method

```
 - (void) touchesEnded: (NSSet *) touches withEvent: (UIEvent *) event {}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but this does not work. it has same issue as described. the custom view is blocking the event...

Comment: @user1118019 :) if the custom views are imageview and labels, i think it is ok. Have you tried to NSLog in the touchesEnded method?

Comment: @user1118019 the button will block the event.